# Bootable USB for Windows and Linux Installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb, windows, usb-drive

I just got a new 64GB USB 3.0 flash drive, and I want to be able to install the various flavors of Windows and Ubuntu from that flash drive. The Windows USB Tool only installs the different versions of Windows, while UNetbootin installs just about everything but Windows. One needs the flash drive to be formatted as NTFS, the other, Fat32. Could I partition the flash drive to make it work with both USB tools? Is there any way for Windows and Linux installers to coexist on the same flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

Hey have found that Yumi is a very good tool for this. Although you can not install server edition of Ubuntu from it. You can do the desktop and windows plus it is easy to learn. Here is the link http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/